# simple c# class to f#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

How would this class look in f#?

```
public class myClass : baseClass
{
    public myClass()
    {
        this.someVariable = "test";
        this.someFunction();
    }
}
```

So far i've figured out (is it even correct?):

```
type myClass = class
        inherit baseClass
        new ()= 
            this.someFunction()
end
```

but am struggling with calling someFunction() as it says 'this' is not defined

Comment: You need to define a constructor. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I recommend reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233192.aspx for all the details about how to make classes in F#.

Comment: Also see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timng/archive/2010/04/05/f-object-oriented-programming-quick-guide.aspx for a side by side comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to translate your code:

```
type baseClass() =
    member this.someFunction() = printf "hello world\n"

type myClass() as this =
    inherit baseClass()
    let mutable someVariable = "test"
    do this.someFunction()
```

Comment: Thank you. msdn link very useful, 'as this' was the biggest thing I missed.

Comment: For others with the same confusion, the code for setting someVariable (where it's inherited from the base class) is 'do this.someVariable <- "test"'